# Karma vs Chutzpah

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, chutzpah

I have been trying to figure out what is the best way to write/run automated jasmine tests in visual studio. Currently, I am using jasmine with Resharper (using PhantomJS) and the test can be run from visual studio. Now I want to run the tests as part of continuous integration and very are using TFS. Searching online give me few options which made me rather confused.

1) Use Chutzpah as a test runner to execute jasmine tests.

2) Use Karma as a test runner (but it also requires Chutzpah test adaptor for visual studio).

I get the feeling that using Karma is somewhat better than anything else but I couldn't understand the benefits of Karma instead of just using Chutzpah. Can anyone please clarify what should be the usage?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER:** I am the author of Chutzpah so take anything I say with a pinch of bias.

Both Karma and Chutzpah are both good tools to be able to run JavaScript unit tests. Karma is the more active open source project and has a large group of people contributing to it. It is very configurable and lets you (as Sean says) target browser besides Phantom. There are VS plugins for it as well but I have not used them much.

Chutzpah is a mature product that is also very configurable. It will always run your tests in PhantomJS but does let you open them in a new browser in order to debug. Chutzpah VS integration is mature and seamless.

Comment: is there a way with to run the test when a test/file is modified in chutzpah like autoWatch in karma?

Comment: If using Visual Studio yes, but from the command line not yet. I plan to add this feature eventually though

Comment: @MatthewManela How do you make the tests run when a file is modified within Visual Studio?

Comment: There is an option in the test explorer that says "run tests after build". This is unfortunate wording but for Chutzpah means "run tests after save"

Comment: @MatthewManela I am sorry I went to the link https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/wiki/Chutzpah.json-Settings-File and tried to find out "run tests after build" property I could not find it . Can you point me to some sample where do we put this property and what is exactly its name in chutzpah.json ?

Comment: It is not in the chutzpah.json, it is in the Test Explorer UI in Visual Studio.

Answer (score -1):

The biggest benefit of Karma over Chutzpah is it can be configured to use Chrome (or any other browser) to be the test runner which makes tests a lot easier to debug with browser developer tools.

Comment: You can debug tests with Chutzpah too if you choose the option to "Open in browser".

Comment: Chutzpah also lets debug directly in VS which some people prefer.