# Difference between Chutzpah & Karma test runners

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, chutzpah

I was looking in to the test runners and i was confused with these two of them,many people were saying karma is the best but as these two are just runners to run the jasmine code written,what is there specifical about karma?
What exactly is the difference between these two?
Which one is good enough for jasmine unit tests of AngularJs?
If karma hw can we include karma runner in visual studio?
Kindly Help!!!
Thank You.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Karma vs Chutzpah](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30868041/karma-vs-chutzpah)

Answer (score 0):

Karma has larger group of people contributing to it. It has a lot of configurations and you can target browser besides Phantom. You can use it within Visual Studio using some plugins. [For example this one](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4cd59e4a-82e8-4b4e-8302-d102fc81b090)

Chutzpah has way less contributers, but this doesn't mean its not mature enough. There are plugins for VS and other IDE/TE as well, but on the other hand it limits you to test only in PhantomJS. Other browsers needs to be opened with debbug tools.

Comment: AFAIK Chutzpah has an option to open in browser - i've seen it mentioned in some other questions here on Stack. [Mentioned in a comment on this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30870400/1463725)